# USB flash drive is read-only under Gnome on Debian

Tags: debian, mount, gnome, usb

I have Debian on my PC. I insert a USB flash and it open just fine in my Gnome environment. But when I try to copy something in it I get:

> Error during copy.The destination is only for reading.

When I go to properties to see if I can change something from there it seems I cannot — the change I am making resets on it's own.

What should I do?

#### EDIT

If I use `mount` I get:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/KINGSTON type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437‌​,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udi‌​sks)
```

and

```
# mount -o remount,rw/dev/sdb1/
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.
       mount -a [-t|-O] ...     : mount all stuff from /etc/fstab
       mount device             : mount device at the known place
       mount directory          : mount known device here
       mount -t type dev dir    : ordinary mount command
Note that one does not really mount a device, one mounts
a filesystem (of the given type) found on the device.
One can also mount an already visible directory tree elsewhere:
       mount --bind olddir newdir
or move a subtree:
       mount --move olddir newdir
One can change the type of mount containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-shared dir
       mount --make-slave dir
       mount --make-private dir
       mount --make-unbindable dir
One can change the type of all the mounts in a mount subtree
containing the directory dir:
       mount --make-rshared dir
       mount --make-rslave dir
       mount --make-rprivate dir
       mount --make-runbindable dir
A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,
or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .
Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].
For many more details, say  man 8 mount .

# remount
bash: remount: command not found
# mount -t remount,rw/dev/sdb1/
# mount -t remount,rw/dev/sdb1/
#
```

Why?

Comment: From the wording of your question, it seems you're using some GUI? Which one? Debian includes many, many file managers. Which desktop environment are you using (Gnome3, Cinnamon, KDE, LXDE, …)?

Comment: I 'd say gnome.

Answer (score 2):

Check dmesg.

Perhaps, the file system has been set read-only 
because the volume had not been properly unmounted
and some data may be corrupt.

Is such case, you should unmount the file system and run fsck.

Answer (score 1):

Unmount the USB-drive and open up a new terminal.

First get the device name with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

(Example: /dev/sdb1)

Create new a mount point:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb
```

Then mount the USB-drive back on with ownership set to you:

```
sudo mount -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb/
```

In the command above, the only thing you have to change is the device name `/dev/sdb1` to the one you found with the `fdisk` command.

Now you will have the ownership of the USB-drive and can do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I try typing what you posted but i get:

paranoia@dbn-up:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for paranoia: 
paranoia is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but as I commented, there appears to be a problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to mount with async options,i heard somewhere that sync is dangerous for usb pen

Comment: @elbarna         How to do that?

Comment: mount  -o async /dev/yourpen /mnt/whereyouwant or edit fstab and options must be defaults,async if you get error on dmesg about usb trasnfer blocked or i/o errors consider the pen faulty or near faulty,but before this try another pen,or same pen on another usb port

Comment: @elbarna             I 've also done that. It says: Only root can do that. I will attempt a suicide soon:)

Comment: @elbarna       Does the whereyouwant means a new destination or the one that has my USB flash memory?

Comment: new destination of course,where do you want /mnt/pen /mnt/hdpen /mnt/usb

Comment: @str : Could you please tell me how you think I  should unmount ?

Comment: @srt     If I use mount I get: /dev/sdb1 on /media/KINGSTON type vfat (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to mount an NTFS drive that would only come up as read only.  I then installed NTFS-3G and it then came up read/write.

```
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```